# Laplace transform of a signal over t

Tags: laplace-transform

I tried to identify a formula that is appropriate for computing the Laplace transform of
$$f(t)=\displaystyle\frac{\cos 2t-\cos 3t}{t}$$
but I couldn't find one. Give me a suggestion please. Thanks, Alex.

Comment: Can you prove that if the Laplace transform of $f(t)$ is $F(s)$, then the Laplace transform of $f(t)/t$ is $\int_s^\infty F(r)\ dr$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform

Comment: As @BR suggested, take laplace of the numerator and use the laplace transform for f(t)/t to get the final answer.

Comment: @B R   and @ TenaliRaman Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
\int\limits_s^\infty G(u)\cdot\text du
&=\int\limits_s^\infty\int\limits_0^\infty g(t)e^{-ut}\cdot\text dt\cdot\text du
\\&=\int\limits_0^\infty g(t)\int\limits_s^\infty e^{-ut}\cdot\text du\cdot\text dt
\\&=\int\limits_0^\infty g(t)\left.\frac{e^{-ut}}{-t}\right|_s^\infty \cdot\text dt
\\&=\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{g(t)}te^{-st}\cdot\text dt
\\&=\mathcal L\left\{\frac {g(t) }t \right\}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: $$f(t)=\frac{g(t)}t$$